# How can I use openMP for this loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm wondering if it is feasible to make this loop parallel using openMP.

Of coarse there is the issue with the race conditions.  I'm unsure how to deal with the n in the inner loop being generated by the outerloop, and the race condition with where D=A[n].  Do you think it is practical to try and make this parallel?

```
for(n=0; n < 10000000; ++n) {   

    for (n2=0; n2< 100; ++n2) {
        A[n]=A[n]+B[n2][n+C[n2]+200];

        }

    D=D+A[n];

}
```

Comment: Note that `n2` in the inner loop doesn't depend upon `n` in any way -- you could replace that inner loop with 100 explicitly written lines without any trouble...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed parallelizable assuming none of the pointers are aliased.

```
int D = 0;  //  Or whatever the type is.

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:D) private(n2)
for (n=0; n < 10000000; ++n) {   

    for (n2 = 0; n2 < 100; ++n2) {
        A[n] = A[n] + B[n2][n + C[n2] + 200];
    }

    D += A[n];
}
```

It could actually be optimized somewhat as follows:

```
int D = 0;  //  Or whatever the type is.

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:D) private(n2)
for (n=0; n < 10000000; ++n) {   

    int tmp = A[n]
    for (n2 = 0; n2 < 100; ++n2) {
        tmp += B[n2][n + C[n2] + 200];
    }

    A[n] = tmp;
    D += tmp;
}
```

Comment: `(+:D)` looks like a smiley... ugh, can't unsee.

Comment: Not my idea to use `D`. :) But I guess there's plenty others you could use: `(+:P)`, `(+:O)`, `+:XD`...

Comment: LOL. you could also have used `(+:vI)`.  Thanks for the help, that was actually very simple to do.  Unfortunately my program takes longer to execute using omp in this instance.

Comment: I think, n2 should be made private!?

Comment: @Bort Yes, you are correct. It needs to be private or declared inside the loop. Dunno how I overlooked it. Fixed. :D

Comment: Wow that made a big difference!  Without the OMP directive it took about 80 seconds, with the OMP about 20 seconds, and without n2 being private, about 125 seconds.

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't have even been correct without the `private`. As for why it's faster, that has to do with cache coherence as all the threads were fighting over the same copy of `n2`.